# Why PropertyDescriptor(String, Class) constructor uses isFieldName() as the getter name?

Tags: java, reflection

I would expect the constructor to test for both getFieldName() and isFieldName() getters. Why is IS_PREFIX the default prefix?

Source code : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.java#PropertyDescriptor.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Class%29

I use Java 1.8.0_31_b13.

How I use it :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    class Foo { String bar; public String getBar(){return bar;} public void setBar(String b){this.bar=b;} }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        java.beans.PropertyDescriptor p = new java.beans.PropertyDescriptor("bar", Foo.class);
        System.out.println(p.getReadMethod().getName()); // prints getBar, not consistent with source code
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/5pm0lA

The code prints `getBar` but I don't get why.

Comment: @Tunaki I fixed the code and provided a runnable example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code prints getBar but I don't get why.

The javadoc states

> Constructs a `PropertyDescriptor` for a property that follows the
>   standard Java convention by having `getFoo` and `setFoo` accessor methods.
>   Thus if the argument name is "fred", it will assume that the writer
>   method is `setFred` and the reader method is `getFred` (or `isFred`
>   for a `boolean` property).

You've provided a `propertyName` of `bar`, your class has an accessible accessor named `getBar`, that's what's returned.

> I would expect the constructor to test for both getFieldName() and
>   isFieldName() getters. Why is IS_PREFIX the default prefix?

You have access to the source code, down the rabbit hole we go. Specifically, look at the logic of the [`getReadMethod`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.java#PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod%28%29) method. The prefix set in the constructor is overwritten in that method if a getter with a `get` prefix is found.

---

Pre-question change:

Your accessor and mutator are not `public`. The [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html#PropertyDescriptor%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) first attempts to find `public` getter/setter with the `get`/`set` prefix (following conventions), then attempts with `is` for `boolean` properties. The error message is just telling you the last thing that it tried.

Make your properties `public`.

Comment: Sorry I wrote my getters/setters too quickly. I agree Reflection may have issues if the method visibility isn't public. I edited my question to reflect what I expect as an answer.

Comment: Please re read the 1st line of my question. The source states it uses IS_PREFIX but obviously the compiled code is not.

Comment: @pyb You have access to the source code. Just keep following the execution of the constructor, which eventually reaches the `getReadMethod` method.

Comment: the constructor I linked in the question calls the PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, beanClass, readMethodName, writeMethodName). http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.java#89 So `IS_PREFIX + propertyName` is used for the `readMethodName` argument.

Comment: Keep following the execution. It's all in there. It eventually calls `getReadMethod` which checks another prefix.

Comment: Thanks, everything is in the getReadMethod :)